# автоматическая установка расширения через ExtensionInstallForcelist не работает

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Из гайда http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist следует, что данный код в батнике приведет к добавлению расширения в chrome

```
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist" /v "1" /t REG_SZ /d "gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx" /f
```

Но почему-то это не работает)

Каким образом можно установить расширение в хром, есть же партнерки, которые продают инсталы расширений, как это делают они?

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 35 (35.0.1916.114 m), как известно (англ.), браузер Google Chrome для ОС Windows перестал поддерживать установку новых и работу прежде установленных расширений, размещённых не в магазине Chrome WebStore.

https://habrahabr.ru/post/226063/ возможно что-то полезное здесь найдете.